# Word for a large round chamber

Tags: single-word-requests

My university has a library with a large round hall/chamber where students can study. On the sides it is supported by the columns. Is there a special word in English for big round rooms covered by a roof?

Comment: You do mean covered by a dome?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a **rotunda**.

> rotunda [noun]
>
> A round building or room, especially one with a dome.

[[OxfordDictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rotunda)]

But you should have heard the comments when I explained to some tourists that the Radcliffe Camera was 'the rotunda you can see in the distance' rather than 'the round building ...'.

Comment: And if you want a rather splendid example of one, take a look at the [Sheldonian Theatre](http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5c/The_Sheldonian_from_across_Broad_Street.jpg&imgrefurl=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheldonian_Theatre&h=1944&w=2592&tbnid=9WWPxOMKVl7O9M:&zoom=1&tbnh=160&tbnw=213&usg=__04z8M2JLrFoLE8U5agH2D7eMVEE=&docid=HiqAyqcuEtAqHM&itg=1) Oxford, opened in 1669, after a design by Sir Christopher Wren.

Comment: +1, also see [**the Rotunda at the University of Virginia**](http://www.virginia.edu/rotunda/).

Comment: Or for one with a dome go to [the old reading room of the British Museum](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=British+Museum+reading+room&num=50&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0CDkQ7AlqFQoTCIiyptyji8YCFYpXFAodKhIAgg&biw=1366&bih=599#imgrc=G7Qdub8lMHaIXM%253A%3By62bzWAHp-qWjM%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Flavenderfawn.files.wordpress.com%252F2012%252F05%252Fbritish-museum-domed-reading-room.jpg%3Bhttps%253A%252F%252Flavenderfawn.wordpress.com%252Fa-brief-history-of-the-british-library%252F%3B640%3B444), which is where Karl Marx wrote *Das Kapital*.

Comment: @WS2 - Quite a "room"! Even I could write with inspiration there!

Comment: @LittleEva Ever tried reading *Das Kapital*? Your comment brings to mind the adage about 5% inspiration and 95% perspiration.

Comment: I've read it, @WS2, and I know what you mean.

Comment: Or the US Library of Congress' main Reading Room.

Comment: @Novelocrat Is [this](http://blogs.loc.gov/catbird/files/2012/07/mrr.jpg) what you mean - built 1897. I wonder why important reading rooms have tended to be circular?

Comment: @WS2 Central Library, Manchester, has the administration located in the centre, with the work-desks next, and books shelved in outer concentric rings (though stock rarely accessed has to be brought up to the central console by lift). It seems better than having to walk a quarter of a mile to get to admin at the other end of a long room. Though one can still end up doing a lot of walking.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I assume you mean the new civic library. I have not been in there yet (though am an occasional visitor to the University library). I must try it out though my visits to Manchester will soon be curtailed as my daughter is moving to, dare I say it, Birmingham.

Comment: The 1934 neoclassical building has been revamped rather than replaced; the Guardian showed [some photographs](http://www.theguardian.com/books/gallery/2014/mar/21/the-restored-manchester-central-library-a-sneak-peek-in-pictures) (but a tiny fraction of the bookshelves). It's always called 'Central Library' (as opposed to say 'The John Rylands Library').